# Java program of the Backtracking algorithm for the Sum-of-Subsets problem

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I'm currently working on a problem where I'm supposed to implement in Java the backtracking algorithm of the sum-of-subset.

Backtracking is used to solve problems in which a sequence of objects is selected from a specified set so that the sequence satisfies some criteria. In this assignment, you are expected to apply the Backtracking algorithm for the Sum-of-Subsets problem, which is explained as follows:

•   Problem: Given n positive integers (weights) and a positive integer W, determine all combinations of the integers that sum to W.

•   Inputs: Positive integer n, sorted (non-decreasing order) array of positive integers w indexed from 1 to n, and a positive integer W.

•   Outputs: all combinations of the integers that sum to W.

Following our usual convention, n, w, W, and include are not inputs to our routines. If these variables were defined globally, the top-level call to sum_of_subsets would be as follows:

```
sum_of_subsets(0, 0, total);
```

the algorithm included in the book:

```
void sum_of_subsets(index i, 
                    int weight, int total)  {
  if (promising(i))
     if (weight == W)
        cout << include[1] through include [i];
     else {
        include[i + 1] = "yes";               // Include w[i + 1].
        sum_of_subsets(i + 1, weight + w[i + 1], total - w[i + 1]);
        include[i + 1] = "no";                // Do not include w[i + 1].
        sum_of_subsets(i + 1, weight, total - w[i + 1]);
     }
}

bool promising (index i);  {
  return (weight + total >= W) && (weight == W || weight + w[i + 1] <= W);
}
```

I have tried to implement the above algorithm using Java but it's not working

```
public class Backtracking {

    //public static boolean include[];
    public static int W = 52;
    public static int w[] = { 2, 10, 13, 17, 22, 42 };
    public static boolean include[] = new boolean[50];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("solution: ");
        for(int i=0; i<w.length-1;i++) {
            sum_of_subsets(i, w[i], W);
        }

    }

    public static void sum_of_subsets(int i, int weight, int total) {

        if (promising(i, weight, total)) {
            if (weight == W) {
                for (int j = 0; j < w.length; j++) {
                    if(include[j])
                        System.out.println(w[j]);
                }
            } else {
                include[i + 1] = true;
                sum_of_subsets(i + 1, weight + w[i + 1], total - w[i + 1]);
                include[i + 1] = false;
                sum_of_subsets(i + 1, weight, total - w[i + 1]);

            }
            

        }
        
    }

    public static boolean promising(int i, int weight, int total) {
        return (weight + total >= W) && (weight == W || weight + w[i+1] <= W);
    }

}
```

the output i get is wrong i get {17,22} instead of subsets that sums up to 52 like {42,10} , {17,13,22} etc

Comment: _"does not work"_. Mention the input and expected value if your answer is wrong

Comment: @AbhinavMathur   the input is an array { 2, 10, 13, 17, 22, 42 }  and the weight is 52 
the output should be subsets that have the sum of 52 
which are {10,42} and {13,17,22}
but i get no output (blank screen)  which means that the code wasn't able to reach the print statement but I'm not sure why although i followed the algorithm (pseudo code ) provided above

Comment: Seems others found similar problems with this book  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58786012/does-this-algorithm-actually-work-sum-of-subsets-backtracking-algorithm

Comment: The way of calling wrong - you should call sum_of_subsets(0, 0, total); total = sum of all weights, sum of all weights is 106 - You need to call sum_of_subsets(0,0,106)